# Make text stay in middle/center of the page in all screen size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've trying to make my header staying in the middle of the page, doesn't matter what windows-size I'm at.

I've tried using Bootstrap.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
        <h1 class=" section-title ">StackOverflow</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, this CSS.

```
.section-title {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right;auto;
}
```

Then as soon as I shrink my windows down, my header keep going back to the left.
How do I stop that ? What is the best way to do that ?

[My Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/9uor4u13/) - if you need it.

Comment: `margin:0 auto;` is used to center block elements with a specified width. For text you should use `text-align:center;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should replace `;` with `:`. Also to dead centre:

```css
html, body {height: 100%; width: 100%;}
h1 {text-align: center; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;}
.center {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; left: 0; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #ccc; height: 100%; width: 100%; vertical-align: middle;}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <h1>Centered</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to center the text.

```css
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

If you also want to center the element itself.

```css
h1 {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

*Watch the border differences between the two demos.*